# Why are these images not displaying?

Tags: php, html

I run a wampserver on my laptop. I uploaded images to my website using a PHP script, but discovered that some of the images don't display. I checked to see if the images were actually uploaded and exists. They do exist. While one of the images displays both on the remote server and my local server, the other one only shows on my local server. The links are as shown below:

1. `<img src="/upload/80001101/thumb/34_87960974.jpg" width="" height="" />`
2. `<img src="/upload/80001205/thumb/20_52172113.jpg" width="" height="" />`

I downloaded the second image to my server and could see that there was no problem with it. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you specify the directory structure? Try to remove the /before the upload.

Comment: Can you tell where exactly in the directory structure your images are located? (for example: c:\xampp\htdocs\myWebpage\img\upload\.....) with that info it would be possible to exactly tell you where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

If you're directory structure is:

> -->www/
>   ------>upload/
>   ------------->80001101/
>   ---------------------->thumb
>   ---------------------------->34_87960974.jpg

And your code to show the images is in your root(www) directory. Let's say homepage.php. Your code should be like this:

```
<img src="upload/80001101/thumb/34_87960974.jpg" width="" height="" />
```

But if your file is on a subfolder, lets say the structure is like this.

> -->www/
>   ------->home/ 
>   ------------>homepage.php

Your code should look like this:

```
 <img src="../upload/80001101/thumb/34_87960974.jpg" width="" height="" />
```

For a more detailed information of ../ in the url, visit this page http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090205061849AAzDqZH

Hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks so much it did.